# How to use django-registration package?

Tags: python, django, django-registration

I have currently working on django-registration package. I have also configured my project as shown below,

**settings.py**

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yahoo.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'myname@yahoo.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'mypassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587

ACCOUNT_ACTIVATION_DAYS = 7
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'registration',
)
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.default.urls')),
```

[image]

When I click the SignUp button my web browser is loading. But no response from the server side and also my details are stored in database. Please solve my problem.Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like it might be hanging on sending the registration email. According to Yahoo's Mail Help your server setting is incorrect.

> Outgoing server: smtp.mail.yahoo.com.

http://help.yahoo.com/kb/index?page=content&y=PROD_MAIL_ML&locale=en_US&id=SLN3285